# Cannot access files inside Vagrant Sync Folder

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, npm, vagrant

I'm running docker containers inside Vagrant VM (with Vbox 5.0.10 as provider), and here is my Vagrantfile :

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.box_check_update = false

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8585

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.cpus = 2
  end

  config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
     sudo apt-get update
  SHELL

  #Docker
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    #d.build_image "/vagrant/app"
  end

  #Docker-compose
  config.vm.provision :docker_compose, yml: "/vagrant/project/web-project/docker-compose.yml", rebuild: true, run: "always"

end
```

I have node modules in /vagrant/project/web-project/node_modules a folder that generated by npm install.
Almost all files and folders inside node_modules folder are accessible except this folder :

```
 /vagrant/project/web-despatch/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/
node_modules/babel-traverse/node_modules/babel-code-frame/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/has-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js
```

The error is :

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/vagrant/project/web-project/nod
e_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-s
coping/node_modules/babel-traverse/node_modules/babel-code-frame/node_modules/ch
alk/node_modules/has-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js'
```

Then I continue to identify the problem by logging in to the vagrant via ssh:

```
Yoesoff_I@MTPC432 /cygdrive/d/OS/vweb-project
$ vagrant.exe ssh   #yes_I'm_using_cygwin
```

And now I am inside vagrant VM and I go to the folder that files inside can not be found :

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cd /vagrant/project/web-project/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-sc
oping/node_modules/babel-traverse/node_modules/babel-code-frame/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/has-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex/
```

then I try to `ls` and the result is like this :

```
node_modules/babel-traverse/node_modules/babel-code-frame/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/has-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex$ ls
ls: cannot access index.js: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access license: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access package.json: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access readme.md: No such file or directory
index.js  license  package.json  readme.md
```

Anyone could help me resolve this issue ?

Thank you,

Comment: This might be an issue with [long path names](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1953) on Windows and VirtualBox.

Comment: the issue solved by using https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using rsync (you can see the doc in here https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html and dont forget to start it sync daemon https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/rsync-auto.html ).

here is mya sync folder config :

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./project/web-project", "/web-project", type: "rsync", rsync__exclude: ".git/", rsync__args: ["--verbose", "--rsync-path='sudo rsync'", "--archive", "--delete", "-z"]
```

you can start rsync manually using :

```
vagrant.exe rsync-auto
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error when the host for my docker container was nearly out of disk space. Scratched my head and tried a bunch of different things, but didn't get much more info until I was completely out of disk space, then it led me to increase the space available and that resolved it for me.